# How to process the rdf version of a DBpedia page with Jena?

Tags: java, parsing, rdf, jena, dbpedia

In all dbpedia pages, e.g.

http://dbpedia.org/page/Ireland

there's a link to a RDF file.
In my application I need to analyse the rdf code and run some logic on it.
I could rely on the dbpedia SPARQL endpoint, but I prefer to download the rdf code locally and parse it, to have full control over it.

I installed **JENA** and I'm trying to parse the code and extract for example a property called: "geo:geometry".

I'm trying with:

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader( node.rdfCode )      
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel()
model.read( sr, null )
```

How can I query the model to get the info I need?

For example, if I wanted to get the statement:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ireland">
<geo:geometry xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" rdf:datatype="http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#Geometry">POINT(-7 53)</geo:geometry>
</rdf:Description>
```

Or

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ireland">
<dbpprop:countryLargestCity xmlns:dbpprop="http://dbpedia.org/property/" xml:lang="en">Dublin</dbpprop:countryLargestCity>
</rdf:Description>
```

What is the right filter?

Many thanks!
Mulone

Comment: see latest edition of my answer. Now it contains a more complex filter that allows filtering more than one predicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have the file parsed in a Jena model you can iterate and filter with something like:

```
//Property to filter the model
Property geoProperty = 
    model. createProperty("http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#",
                          "geometry");

//Iterator based on a Simple selector
StmtIterator iter =
  model.listStatements(new SimpleSelector(null, geoProperty, (RDFNode)null)); 

//Loop to traverse the statements that match the SimpleSelector
while (iter.hasNext()) {
   Statement stmt = iter.nextStatement();
   System.out.print(stmt.getSubject().toString());
   System.out.print(stmt.getPredicate().toString());
   System.out.println(stmt.getObject().toString());

}
```

The `SimpleSelector` allows you to pass any (subject,predicate,object) pattern to match statements in the model. In your case if you only care about a specific predicate then first and third parameters of the constructor are null.

**Allowing filtering two different properties**

To allow more complex filtering you can implement the `selects` method in the
`SimpleSelector` interface like here:

```
Property geoProperty = /* like before */;
Property countryLargestCityProperty = 
    model. createProperty("http://dbpedia.org/property/",
                          "countryLargestCity");

SimpleSelector selector = new SimpleSelector(null, null, (RDFNode)null) {
    public boolean selects(Statement s)
        { return s.getPredicate().equals(geoProperty) || 
                 s.getPredicate().equals(countryLargestCityProperty) ;}
}
StmtIterator iter = model.listStatements(selector);
while(it.hasNext()) {
     /* same as in the previous example */
}
```

**Edit: including a full example**

This code includes a full example that works for me.

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.SimpleSelector;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Literal;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.StmtIterator;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Statement;

public class TestJena {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileManager fManager = FileManager.get();
        fManager.addLocatorURL();
        Model model = fManager.loadModel("http://dbpedia.org/data/Ireland.rdf");

        Property geoProperty = 
        model. createProperty("http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#",
                                  "geometry");

        StmtIterator iter =
            model.listStatements(new SimpleSelector(null, geoProperty,(RDFNode) null)); 

        //Loop to traverse the statements that match the SimpleSelector
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Statement stmt = iter.nextStatement();
            if (stmt.getObject().isLiteral()) {
                Literal obj = (Literal) stmt.getObject();
                System.out.println("The geometry predicate value is " + 
                                                          obj.getString());
            }   
        }   
    }   

}
```

This full example prints out:

```
The geometry predicate value is POINT(-7 53)
```

**Notes on Linked Data**

`http://dbpedia.org/page/Ireland` is the HTML document version of the resource `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ireland`

In order to get the RDF you should resolve :

`http://dbpedia.org/data/Ireland.rdf`

or

`http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ireland`  +  `Accept: application/rdfxml` in the HTTP header.
With `curl` it'd be something like:

`curl -L -H 'Accept: application/rdf+xml' http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ireland`

Comment: thanks! actually the problem is that the filter on the "geometry" doesn't select anything, even though the statement is clearly in the model. Any idea about that? Thanks again!

Comment: @Mulone see the new edition with a full example. Hopefully it will help to spot the error. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Another quick one: can I use a filter to catch this statement: <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bank"><dcterms:subject xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Bank_buildings"/></rdf:Description>

Comment: if you want to catch all triples with `dcterms:subject` predicates. You just need to create the predicate for the URI http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject where `http://purl.org/dc/terms` would be the namespace and `subject` the name. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Sorry to harrass you again, but I'm trying to get the statement 'subClassOf' from this rdf code: http://dbpedia.org/data3/Continent.rdf Which is the name space in this case? Thanks again for your patience!

Comment: subClassOf is part of the RDFS vocabulary therefore `http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#`